# Error calling a static member function

Tags: c++, static-methods

I've declared a function in a .h file, and I included the .h file in the .cpp where I want to call the function, but I get errors like:

> error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'" or "identifier of (function i'm calling) is undefined

This is the sample code:

### help.h

```
class Help
{
public:
    Help(void);
    ~Help(void);

    static int findItems();

};
```

### wallet.cpp

```
#include "Help.h"

int main()
{
    int choice;
    char ch;

    do{

        cout<<"Please choose an option: \n";
        cout<<"\t1. Locate item. \n";
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"Your choice: ";
        cin>>choice;


        switch(choice)
        {
             case 1:
                 Help.findItems();//this is the problem
                 break;
```

I get the error:

> C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'.

If i change

```
static int findItems();
```

to

```
int findItems();
```

and

```
Help.finditems();
```

to

```
findItems();
```

I get the error:

> identifier "findItems" is undefined. How can i do this properly?

Comment: If you declare it as a static function then try Help::findItems();

Comment: Or create an instance of the `Help` class.

Comment: i want to remove the declaration of static

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either access the function like this:

```
Help::findItems();
```

or create a new object of the `Help` class and write

```
newObject.findItems();
```

You wrote `Help.findItems();` and the reasons you are getting errors are:

1. `Help` is not an object (for which a function could be called)
2. You didn't use the `::` operator, which practically means the function is undefined there.

Answer (score 1):

If you call a static function through a class, you should use a scope resolution operator '::'

```
Help::findItems();
```

Other way to call a (usually non-static) function is through an object of that type. Then use the dot.

```
myHelpObject.findItems();
```

Answer (score 0):

If declaration: `static int findItems()` then call: `Help::findItems()`

Elseif declaration: `int findItems()` then call:`Help h(); h.findItems()`

Elseif declaration: `(outside of class) int findItems()` then call: `findItems()`